# Customizing Kibana 4

Tags: visualization, dashboard, kibana, kibana-4

I want to develop a dashboard similar to `Kibana 4` using `iframe` in a `HTML` page. Only dashboard and visualization menus are required in the `HTML`  page. 
I have already tried using two `iframe tags` for each dashboard and visualization but I'm facing the following problems:

1.) In the visualization page, I can't add a new chart.
2.) I don't see any edit or cancel buttons on the dashboard charts.

I have used `embed=true` in `iframe src`

Is there a short way I can overcome this using `iframe`or do I need to go through the `main.css` file and accordingly edit it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need to modify the main.css file in order to accomplish what you want.

You could also inject your own styles that override the ones specified by kibana. The later will probably make maintenance/upgrading a little bit easier.